# Java: Can not write some utf8 chars

Tags: java, file, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with writing some utf8 chars in files with java.
When I try to write Ϣ, everything works fine. But when I try to write “ (U+201C), it doesn't work. Java writes \u201c instead of the char.

```
String content = ""; // some string
final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new 
    OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
try {
    out.write(content);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Can anybody say me, how to write these specific chars?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you construct the string containing the troublesome character.  You may accidentally escape the backslash.

Comment: Yes! My JSON Library escaped them! Thank you!